# How to map through the JSON array of objects in React?

Tags: reactjs

I got a JSON array of objects from the API return, but now I'm having trouble with getting the elements of one of the arrays. Here I am trying to display the data from docs array (20 elements):

```
return(
 <ul>
  {books.docs.map((book, idx) => {
    return (
      <li key={idx}>
        <h3>{book.docs[idx].title}</h3>
        <p>{book.docs.creator[0]}</p>
      </li>
    );
  })}
 </ul>);
```

[API return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1GsR.png)

I keep getting error with map function: "books.map is not a function" or "cannot read property map of undefined", where "books" is an object that gives me the data from the screenshot. Any suggestions on how I can solve the problem?

***UPDATE***:
Here is how I'm fetching the data:

```
  const Books = () => {

  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const fetchBooks = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(`${API_URL}`);
      setBooks(result.data);
    }
    catch (error) {
      setError(true);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const onInputChange = e => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  }

  const onSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchBooks();
  }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Search onSubmitHandler={onSubmitHandler} searchTerm={searchTerm} onInputChange={onInputChange} error={error} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Loader loading={loading}>
            Fetching
          </Loader>
          <BookList books={books} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );}
```

Comment: How are you fetching the data? Are you awaiting the responds properly? Are you parsing the json? Show us that bit of the code

Comment: you need to handle the case when you are fetching data and your variable `books` is not yet populated with the response. Maybe show a loading icon and then render your `ul` when you have data.

Comment: You probably fetch your data when your component mounts, so the data isn't fetched until long after the first render, and you're trying to loop over an empty books object. If you want help, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this question to make it suitable for Stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated the post to show how I am fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
   return(
     <ul>
      {books.docs.map((book, idx) => {
        const {title, creator} = book;
        return (
          <li key={idx}>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <p>{creator[0]}</p>
          </li>
        );
      })}
     </ul>);
```

and you seem to miss [idx] in here

```
book.docs.creator[0]
book.docs[idx].creator[0]
```

Comment: It still gives me an error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"...

Comment: you need to add null(undefined) check condition

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but before the data is fetched, `books` is an empty array, so `books.docs` is undefined and it's not possible to map through an undefined variable.

What happens if you check if `books.docs` is defined before using `.map()` ?

```
return(
 <ul>
  {book.docs && books.docs.map((book, idx) => {
    return (
      <li key={idx}>
        <h3>{book.title}</h3>
        <p>{book.creator[0]}</p>
      </li>
    );
  })}
 </ul>);
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = React.useState([])
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // setTimeout() simulates the time needed to fetch the data from the api
    setTimeout(() => {
      setBooks({
        docs: [
          {
            title: 'Title',
            creator: [
              'Creator'
            ]
          },
          {
            title: 'Title2',
            creator: [
              'Creator2'
            ]
          }
        ]
      })
    }, 1000)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {books.docs && books.docs.map((book, idx) => {
          return (
            <li key={idx}>
              <h3>{book.title}</h3>
              <p>{book.creator[0]}</p>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In case any of your book object is null.

```
return books.docs.length ?(
  <ul>
    {books.docs.map((book, idx) => {
      return book ? (
        <li key={idx}>
          <h3>{book.title ? book.title : ""}</h3>
          <p>{book.creator ? book.creator[0]:""}</p>
        </li>
      ) : null;
    })}
  </ul>
):null;
```